# Why pointer to structure element is not working on sscanf?

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

I need help with a C function I'm trying to do:

```
#define MAXLEN 128
typedef struct
{
    char *title;
    char *autor;
    int year;
    int num_sh;
    char *sec_sh;
    int flooor;
    char *building;
    char *city;
} book;

void csvToStruct(char *line, book *pBook)
{
    char sec_sh[MAXLEN], title[MAXLEN], autor[MAXLEN], building[MAXLEN], city[MAXLEN];
    int year, num_sh, flooor;
    sscanf(line, "\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\",%d,%d,\"%[^\"]\",%d,\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\"",
           title, autor, &year, &num_sh, sec_sh, &flooor, building, city);

    pBook->title = title;
    pBook->autor = autor;
    pBook->year = year;
    pBook->num_sh = num_sh;
    pBook->sec_sh = sec_sh;
    pBook->flooor = flooor;
    pBook->building = building;
    pBook->city = city;
}
```

I was trying to, instead of asigning my strucure elements values using `pBook->element=value`, putting `pBook->element` directly into sscanf. But it isn't working. Why it doesn't work?
In my main function, I'm calling csvToStruct in the following way:

```
int main(void)
{
    book newBook = (book*)malloc(sizeof(book));
    csvToStruct(line, newBook);
};
```

The `line` variable is of type `char *` that I'm getting from a csv file using `fgets()` function.

Comment: You're assigning pointers to local variables, which become invalid when the function returns.

Comment: You should allocate copies of the strings that you parse in the `sscanf()` line. Using `strdup()` would be a good way to do it.  You must check that `sscanf()` returns 8; if it doesn't, the data was erroneous and should not be used (but the good news is that you have the entire line with which to report the error).

Comment: You have to use `&(pBook->element)` for the `int` elements. And for the `char*` elements, you need to allocate memory for them (e.g. with `malloc()`) before you can read into them.

Comment: @Barmar: the parentheses are not needed: `&pBook->element` works fine and is clearer IMO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can never remember the precedence relation between`&` and `->`, so I consider it clearer with the parentheses.

Comment: The dot and arrow operators bind extremely tightly.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to guess what you old code looked like (its frustrating when you say - "I tried changing this code to something else and it didnt work", but dont show that code you tried).

Anyway you did this (simplifying to one field)

```
      sscanf(line, "%s",pBook->title);
```

this doesnt work becuase `pbook->title` doesnt point to any valid memory to store the data in.

You can do a few things

Reserve space in the book struct

```
typedef struct
{
    char title[MAXLEN];

} book;
```

Or you can allocate some heap memory of the correct size so as not to be so wasteful., sadly that is not doable in a one liner  because we need to know how big it is.

This is what you must do (your old code was wrong too and will be fixed the same)

```
 sscanf(line, "%s", title);
 pBook->title = strdup(title);
```

strdup will allocate memory of the correct size and copy the string into it for you.

Note that you old code was wrong too, becuaseyou set pBook->title to point to stack memory in this function. That memory is released once this function returns.